# File upload and download using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am looking for suggestions for my program:

One part of my program generates a .csv file that I need to upload to cloud. Essentially, the program should upload the .csv file to cloud and return the url for that location (csv_url)

Another part of my program has to use that csv_url with wget to download this file.

How can I tackle this problem? Will uploading the file to a S3 bucket work for me? How to return a consolidated url in that case? apart from s3 bucket is there any other medium where I can try and upload my file? Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try `boto3` [library from Amazon](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html), its has all the functions your would like to do

> S3, GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/LIST.

PUT Example--

```
 # Upload a new file
 data = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
 s3.Bucket('my-bucket').put_object(Key='test.jpg', Body=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , uploading the file to AWS s3 will definitely work for you and you need nothing else and if you want to do that with python , it's quite easy

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('images/4.jpeg', 'mausamrest', 'test/jkl.jpeg',ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

where **mausamrest** is bucket and **test/jkl.jpeg** is *keyname* or you can say *filename* in s3

and this is how you will have your url

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mausamrest/test/jkl.jpeg

s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/keyname  this is the format of how your object url will be

in my case image is opening in browser as i have done that kind of thing , in your case your csv will get downloaded